# How long should you leave up something left by a coworker?

Tags: professionalism

I recently got married and when I returned back to the office, I found a "congratulations" banner taped up in my cubicle. How long should I leave this up before taking it down?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it is in the way, leave it for a day and then move it. Otherwise, give it a few days and see if anyone says anything. "How long are you going to leave that up?" or "I would have thought you'd take it down by now."

Reuse it. Find an opportunity to "congratulate" someone else and put it up in their cube.

You can always ask another coworker. Some people may be more sensitive about this type of thing, but there's no way to really know.

Have your picture taken in front of it and save it for posterity.

Comment: It's got my name on it, so unfortunately, re-gifting isn't an option in this case :P

Comment: @KyleFalconer - Wait until you hire another Kyle and then congratulate him on being hired :P

Comment: Maybe it is just me, by regifting does not sound nice. It either feels like "I have been waiting for an opportunity to get rid of this and finally you appeared" or "I am so glad you were hired that I will give you this that someone else gave to me" or even "I want to show like if I care but actually I am just recycling..." It is pretty clear that people usually do not keep banners, so just disposing of it (outside work) is the way to go. The picture part is nice, though.

Answer (score 2):

I'd take it down at days end if no one else had. I'd thank everyone and tell them I want to keep it. Then roll it up and take it home.

Comment: Then recycle it.